# How to show popup on all pages

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, header, popup

I am working on **magento 2.1** extension in which i have to show popup on all pages.
I have write a code for popup which is showing on only one page but i want to apply that code on all pages.

Comment: add your layout xml file code for more information .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your module file add this code in your `default.xml` you file path will be **Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="afterbody"  template="Vendor_Modulename::youfile.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Can I show a template to all pages without using a module or does it only work with a module?

Comment: @Black yes you can use theme default.xml

Comment: there is no theme called "default.xml". Oh I noticed that the question is about Magento 2, I still use 1.8 though.

Comment: @Black i am asking you about create layout file in your theme

Comment: I already created a custom layout file called `alert.xml`. Maybe if you have time you can take a look here, I just created a [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228326/magento-1-8-how-to-use-reference-to-show-a-template-on-all-pages)

Comment: @QaisarSatti Sir How to add popup on homepage only??

Comment: @AsadKhan use cms_index_index.xml layout